# Le mot « emphase »

Tags: usage, synonymes, grec

Le mot emphase (venant du grec) a deux significations. Le lemme du dictionnaire en ligne [wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/emphase) dit :

> 1. Affectation pompeuse dans les paroles, dans le débit, dans la mimique
>      et dans les gestes. Enflure, manière de faire l’important devant
>      l’auditoire, de gonfler son discours avec des mots ronflants.
>
> Le dîner
>   fut médiocre et la conversation impatientante. C’est la table d’un
>   mauvais livre, pensait Julien. Tous les plus grands sujets des pensées
>   des hommes y sont fièrement abordés. Écoute-t-on trois minutes, on se
>   demande ce qui l’emporte, de l’emphase du parleur ou de son abominable
>   ignorance. — (Stendhal, Le Rouge et le Noir, 1830)
>
> Après les
>   salutations, où brilla dans toute son emphase la civilité provinciale,
>   le fauteuil de la présidence fut occupé par celui des assistants que
>   son titre semblait y appeler. — (Julie de Quérangal, Philippe de
>   Morvelle, Revue des Deux Mondes, T.2,4, 1833)
>
> Il n’y a pourtant pas là
>   la moindre emphase, on ne te donne pas du génie, on s’adresse à ton
>   cœur. — (Honoré de Balzac, Modeste Mignon, 1844 ; p. 163 de l’éd.
>   Houssiaux de 1855)
>
> Cornudet, en l’écoutant, gardait un sourire
>   approbateur et bienveillant d’apôtre ; de même un prêtre entend un
>   dévot louer Dieu, car les démocrates à longue barbe ont le monopole du
>   patriotisme comme les hommes en soutane ont celui de la religion. Il
>   parla à son tour d’un ton doctrinaire, avec l’emphase apprise dans les
>   proclamations qu’on collait chaque jour aux murs, et il finit par un
>   morceau d’éloquence où il étrillait magistralement cette « crapule de
>   Badinguet ». — (Maupassant, Boule de Suif , 1880)
>
> 2. Mise en relief d'un
>      des constituants de la phrase par l'intonation ou par l'ordre des
>      mots.

Cependant on n'y voit pas d'exemples d'emploi de la seconde signification. Peut-on conclure que cette dernière n'est pas assez répandue ?

Peut-on employer « emphase » couramment comme synonyme d'« accent » dans le contexte de la phrase ci-dessous ?

> Mes activités de recherche sont décrites au Chapitre 3 ; pour veiller à sa clarté, les détails techniques ont été
>   portés jusqu'à un certain niveau uniquement, l’accent étant mis sur les idées maîtresses de mon savoir-faire
>   en recherche.
>
> Mes activités de recherche sont décrites au Chapitre 3 ; pour veiller à sa clarté, les détails techniques ont été
>   portés jusqu'à un certain niveau uniquement, l’emphase étant mise sur les idées maîtresses de mon savoir-faire
>   en recherche.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Premièrement on ne « met » pas d'emphase dans le sens courant du terme ou dans le cadre de la figure de rhétorique, *on parle, déclame avec/sans* emphase ou on constate qu'*il y a emphase*, tels que l'illustrent les exemples présentés. Deuxièmement de manière très littérale une figure qui consiste en la « mise en relief d'un des constituants de la phrase par l'intonation ou par l'ordre des mots » ne serait pas à mon avis intelligiblement « mise », elle serait employée ; c'est par extension qu'on a les emplois en linguistique comme dans *coefficient emphase, transformation d'emphase* (TLFi). Troisièmement dans la phrase donnée en exemple on ne remarque pas d'affection pompeuse et donc le sens ne convient pas, indépendamment de la formulation. Quatrièmement, si la phrase, faisant référence à l'idée d'importance, avait été en anglais formulée selon le modèle *to place or to lay or to put emphasis on something* alors on [traduirait](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/emphasis/578239?q=put%20emphasis%20on#832475) par *mettre l'accent sur qqc.* mais avec le constat du degré on parlerait plutôt probablement de l'*importance* ; sauf qu'il n'y a aucun lien entre cette importance et l'[emphase](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/emphase) en français, alors que c'est avec le sens d'[*emphasis*](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/emphasis) en anglais qu'elle est reliée. Enfin on a plusieurs autres choix afin d'éviter le calque de l'anglais *mettre de l'emphase sur* dont *mettre l'accent sur, insister sur, mettre en relief, souligner, faire ressortir, attirer l'attention sur, mettre en évidence* ([BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=1884)).

Answer (score 1):

1/ Non, le manque d'exemple ne signifie pas que le terme soit peu usité.

2/ « Accent » est un synonyme assez exact de « emphase », ce que l'on peut [vérifier](http://crisco.unicaen.fr/des/synonymes/emphase) au DES et les deux mots sont plus ou moins interchangeables mais dans certain cas seulement.

Dans le présent cas il me semble que « accent » soit le seul terme qui convienne ; « emphase » est utilisé pour des termes particuliers dans le texte, pas pour un aspect donné du texte dans son ensemble.

> (TLFi) Mettre l'accent sur, faire porter l'accent sur... Mettre en relief, faire ressortir, insister sur tel aspect partic.

- « Il n'y est pas arrivé ! » dit-il avec emphase. *pas « accent » dans ce cas-ci*
- Il voulait mettre l'accent sur la nécessité d'aller vite.

3/ Il est préférable de dire « la **description** des détails techniques a été portée jusqu'à un certain niveau **seulement** ». S'il s'agit d'une restriction sur le nombre des détails il vaut mieux dire « le **nombre** des détails techniques **a été limité** à un minimum ».